# why are the reactive functions not working? (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, reactive

This is a simple case of reactivity not working in R Shiny, however when I search other questions none of the solutions apply to me.

Example Data:

```
gender <- c("F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M")

height_cm <- c(160, 170, 180, 165, 175, 185)

weight_kgs <- c(50, 60, 70, 55, 65, 75)

data <- cbind(gender, height_cm, weight_kgs)





############################ UI code ##############################

sidebar_panel <- sidebarPanel( 
                               
                               
                               ## ------------------ Gender --------------------
                               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "gender",
                                                  label = "Gender",
                                                  choices = unique(data$gender),
                                                  selected = NULL,
                                                  inline = FALSE,
                                                  width = NULL,
                                                  choiceNames = NULL,
                                                  choiceValues = NULL),
                               
                               
                               ## ------------------ Height -------------------- 
                               sliderInput(inputId = "height",
                                           label = "Height (cm)",
                                           value = c(160, 180),
                                           min = 140,
                                           max = 250,
                                           step = 1),
                               
                               
                               ## ------------------ Weight -------------------- 
                               sliderInput(inputId = "weight",
                                           label = "Weight (kg)",
                                           value = c(70, 100),
                                           min = 50,
                                           max = 250,
                                           step = 1)



#------------------------------------- User Interface ---------------------------------#


# Set up UI object

ui <- navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                 title = 'Dashboard',
                 
                 
                 tabPanel('Measurements',
                          
                          useShinyjs(),
                          
                          # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
                          sidebarLayout(
                              
                              # Sidebar panel for inputs
                              sidebar_panel,
                              
                              # Main panel for displaying outputs
                              mainPanel(
                                  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                              
                                              # *Output() functions
                                              
                                              tabPanel("Height & Weight",
                                                       
                                                       fluidRow(
                                                         column(6, plotlyOutput("height_graph", height = "100%")),
                                                         
                                                         column(6, plotlyOutput("weight_graph", height = "100%"))
                                                       )
                                              ),
                                              
                                              tabPanel("BMI",
                                                       plotlyOutput("gender_graph", height = "100%")
                                              ),
                                              
                                              tabPanel("Height vs Weight",
                                                       plotlyOutput("heightvsweight_graph", height = "100%")
                                              )
                                  )
                              )
                          )
                 )
                 
                 
)
```

My UI is fine, the app loads perfectly and looks the way I want it to.

However on the server side, I've tried the following options to make it reactive but none results in me being able to use the inputs to subset the data.

*For demonstration purposes I will only attempt to plot output$height_graph*

### Option 1 - filter data with plotly syntax

```
# Set up server object

server <- function(input, output) {


output$height_graph <- renderPlotly({
      
      data%>%
        filter(weight_kgs %in% input$weight) %>%
        filter(height_cm %in% input$height) %>%
        filter(gender %in% input$gender) %>%
        plot_ly(x = ~height_cm)%>%
        add_histogram()
  
    })


}

# Knit UI and server objects together

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Results

[image: Results from Option 1]

The intended graph (height) is that shown on the left hand side. The weight graph to the right is how it is supposed to look, however that one is not reactive.

### Option 2  - filter data with ggplot2 syntax

```
# Set up server object

server <- function(input, output) {


output$height_graph <- renderPlotly({


      h_graph <- data%>%

      filter(weight_kgs %in% input$weight) %>%
      filter(height_cm %in% input$height) %>%
      filter(gender %in% input$gender) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=height_cm, fill = gender, colour = gender)) +
      geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.5) +
      theme(legend.position="top")+
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(120,max(data$height_cm)))+
      theme_minimal() +
      labs(title="Height histogram",x="Height (cm)", y = "Count")

      ggplotly(h_graph)
      
    })



}

# Knit UI and server objects together

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Results

[image]

The intended graph (height) is that shown on the left hand side. The weight graph to the right is how it is supposed to look, however that one is not reactive.

### Option 3 - create a reactive data frame

```
# Set up server object

server <- function(input, output) {







     ​### MAKE REACTIVE ###
     ​
       ​h <- reactive({
       ​req(input$height)
       filter(data, weight_kgs %in% input$weight)
       ​filter(data, height_cm %in% input$height)
       ​filter(data, gender %in% input$gender)
       })​
       ​
       ​### or ###
       ​
     ​# ​h <- reactive({
     # data %>%
     # filter(weight_kgs %in% input$weight)%>%
     ​# filter(height_cm %in% input$height)%>%
     # ​filter(gender %in% input$gender)  
     ​# })
     ​
       ​### Plot ###

     ​h_graph <- plot_ly(data= h(), x = ~height_cm)%>%
     ​           add_histogram()
     ​ 
     ​ggplotly(h_graph)

}

# Knit UI and server objects together

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Results

[image]

The intended graph (height) is that shown on the left hand side. The weight graph to the right is how it is supposed to look, however that one is not reactive.

### Conclusions

In addition to the graphs not showing what is intended, none of them reacts to the inputs on the sidebar.

If anyone could shed some light on what I am doing wrong and help find a solution, I'd be very thankful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you are working with the reactive inputs correctly. The problem is your filter function.

```
filter(data, height %in% input%input)
```

is not working correctly, because the input is no vector of all elements that are "allowed" to be in height. Sliderinput returns a vector with 2 elements, input$slider[1] being the lower one, input$slider[2] being the higher one. Here is your code in a working example. Notice that i've edited the sample data! To simplify your code, you could also use `dplyr::between()`

```html
gender <- rep(c("M","F"),500)

height_cm <- abs(rnorm(1000,0,5))*10+150

weight_kgs <- abs(rnorm(1000,0,5))*10+50

data <- tibble::tibble(gender, height_cm, weight_kgs) #added tibble here


############################ UI code ##############################

sidebar_panel <- sidebarPanel( 
  
  
  ## ------------------ Gender --------------------
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "gender",
                     label = "Gender",
                     choices = unique(data$gender),
                     selected = NULL,
                     inline = FALSE,
                     width = NULL,
                     choiceNames = NULL,
                     choiceValues = NULL),
  
  
  ## ------------------ Height -------------------- 
  sliderInput(inputId = "height",
              label = "Height (cm)",
              value = c(160, 180),
              min = 140,
              max = 250,
              step = 1),
  
  
  ## ------------------ Weight -------------------- 
  sliderInput(inputId = "weight",
              label = "Weight (kg)",
              value = c(70, 100),
              min = 50,
              max = 250,
              step = 1)
)
  
  
  #------------------------------------- User Interface ---------------------------------#
  
  
  # Set up UI object
  
  ui <- navbarPage(theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("united"),
                   title = 'Dashboard',
                   
                   
                   tabPanel('Measurements',
                            
                            
                            # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
                            sidebarLayout(
                              
                              # Sidebar panel for inputs
                              sidebar_panel,
                              
                              # Main panel for displaying outputs
                              mainPanel(
                                tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                            
                                            # *Output() functions
                                            
                                            tabPanel("Height & Weight",
                                                     
                                                     fluidRow(
                                                       column(6, plotlyOutput("height_graph", height = "100%")),
                                                       
                                                       column(6, plotlyOutput("weight_graph", height = "100%"))
                                                     )
                                            ),
                                            
                                            tabPanel("BMI",
                                                     plotlyOutput("gender_graph", height = "100%")
                                            ),
                                            
                                            tabPanel("Height vs Weight",
                                                     plotlyOutput("heightvsweight_graph", height = "100%")
                                            )
                                )
                              )
                            )
                   )
                   
                   
  )
  
  # Set up server object
  
  server <- function(input, output) {

    output$height_graph <- renderPlotly({
      
      h_graph <- data %>%
        filter(weight_kgs >= input$weight[1]) %>% # here you have to filter the vector in another way
        filter(weight_kgs <= input$weight[2]) %>% # same as above
        filter(height_cm >= input$height[1]) %>% # same as above
        filter(height_cm <= input$height[2]) %>% # same as above
        filter(gender %in% c(input$gender)) %>% #here it works
        ggplot(aes(x=height_cm, fill = gender, colour = gender)) +
        geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.5) +
        theme(legend.position="top")+
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(120,max(data$height_cm)))+
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(title="Height histogram",x="Height (cm)", y = "Count")
      
      ggplotly(h_graph)
      
    })
    
    
  }
  
  # Knit UI and server objects together
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```